# Enabling two Spring Data repositories (neo4j and h2) in the same application context

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-neo4j

I can't seem to get SDN (latest snapshot) to play nicely along side Spring Data JPA (H2).  I do not need transacational support across both data stores; instead my desire is to simply utilize repositories for both stores in the same class.  For example

```
public MySpringControlledClass{

   @Autowired
   private MyNeo4jBasedRepository myNeo4jBasedRepository;

   @Autowired
   private MyH2BasedRepository myH2BasedRepoistory;
   ...
}
```

When I enable both neo4j and JPA I get an exception of the form

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'myNeo4jBasedRepository': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through method 'setMappingContext' parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext] is defined:
>   expected single matching bean but found 2:
>   neo4jMappingContext,jpaMappingContext

Which is as expected given that I now have two mapping contexts, one implicitly created by SDN and one explicitly created in my configuration for spring data JPA.

While I have found posts describing how to do this with two different databases in spring data jpa, I haven't found an example of how to do it with SDN and a spring data JPA store such as H2.  The difference seems to be that SDN hides some of the boilderplate logic from the developer.

Any help would be much appreciated as I have spent a nice chunk of time trying various things and none have proven fruitful thus far.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Similar issue for 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT is logged here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/268

Comment: As mentioned below, I did find a couple of issues logged with neo4j describing a similar issue.  I will submit the simple fix to SDN so that others can get past this issue.  Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in your `myNeo4jBasedRepository` there is a `setMappingContext` method which is auto-wired, and it doesn't know whether to use `neo4jMappingContext` or `jpaMappingContext` because both those beans have the same type as the dependency.

I'm not sure how much is exposed to you but if possible in your `MyNeo4jBasedRepository` override your `setMappingContext` method to take a type of whatever the neo4jMappingContext bean's type is to get it to select this one.

Or override `setMappingContext` method as simply `super.setMappingContext` and put a qualifier `@Qualifier("neo4jMappingContext")` at the top:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("neo4jMappingContext")
public void setMappingContext(TODO todo)
{
  //super.setMappingContext(todo) Sample implementation as before
}
```

This will ensure Spring selects the correct dependency.

Comment: Thanks Snickers3192!  You led me down the right path.  While you can't override the setMappingContext in the repository itself, I found that by adding the @Qualifier you mentioned above to the Neo4jRepositoryFactoryBean, everything worked as you described.  Thanks again!  I will submit this to the SDN folks as I think it would solve some of the bugs Jasper Blues mentioned above.

Comment: Glad I could be of service.

Answer (score 2):

There has been a bug fix pushed to Spring Data Neo4j `4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` which means you don't need to use the `@Qualifier`anymore or define a `MappingContext` bean in your configuration. You will only need to define the respective `PlatformTransactionManager`s and link them to your `@EnableXXXRepositories` through the `transactionManagerRef` attribute.

I have created a project here to demonstrate how to get the two Spring Data projects working together with Spring Boot: https://github.com/mangrish/spring-data-jpa-neo4j-with-boot.